# std::is_same equivalent for unspecialised template types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In one project I have found a possibility to stay DRY as a lot of code except for some small parts could stay the same for template specialisations of a template. 
Here is a small working example what I'm currently doing to check which templated class I'm using:

```
template<typename T>
class A{};

template<typename T>
class B{};

template<template<class> class C>
void do_stuff()
{
    if(std::is_same<A<int>,C<int>>::value)
    {
    // Do Stuff for A
    } else if(std::is_same<B<int>,C<int>>::value)
    // Do Stuff for B
    }
}

int main()
{
    do_stuff<A>();
}
```

What I would like to do instead is using

```
std::is_same<A,C>::value
```

to determine the template type. Is there any function that could help me or am I missing a pattern that would work better in this case?

I see that I could do something like

```
template<template<class> class C, typename T>
void do_stuff();

do_stuff<A,T>();
```

but that seems like the wrong way to do for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could write an `is_same_template` trait which is partially specialized for when the two template template parameters are the same:

```
template <template <typename...> class, template<typename...> class> 
struct is_same_template : std::false_type{};

template <template <typename...> class T>
struct is_same_template<T,T> : std::true_type{};
```

Then you can write `is_same_template<A,C>::value`.

Note that this won't work for templates which have non-type template parameters, like `std::array`.

Some compilers will not consider an alias template to be equivalent to the template it aliases, so the following would result in `std::false_type`:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
using MyVec = std::vector<T, Alloc>;

is_same_template<std::vector, MyVec>;
```

This is considered a [defect in the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286), but you shouldn't rely on behaviour until this fix is implemented in all common compilers.

---

That said, you need to be careful about what you put in those `if` branches, as the code needs to compile regardless of what the template is instantiated with. In C++17 you'll be able to use `if constexpr` to solve this problem, but for now you'll need to tag dispatch or have different specializations if the branches have code which is only valid for `A` or `B`.

```
template <template <typename...> class> struct tag{};

template <template <typename> class T>
void do_stuff() {
    do_stuff(tag<T>{});
}

void do_stuff(tag<A>) {
    std::cout << "A";
}

void do_stuff(tag<B>) {
    std::cout << "B";   
}
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that, under the current language rules, if one argument is an alias template like `template<class... Ts> using B = A<Ts...>;`, `is_same_template<A, B>` will be `false_type`. Many people find this counter-intuitive at first.

Comment: @bogdan Thanks, I added a note.